# How to add additional Azure AD Attributes as Claims with Owin/Open ID Connect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, owin, openid-connect

I would like to add additional Azure AD attributes as Claims to a ClaimsPrincipal created by the "out-of-the-box" ASP.NET MVC template (i.e. `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(...)`)

I tried implementing something similar in the `SecurityTokenValidated` notification as shown in [this article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/26/augmenting-the-set-of-incoming-claims-with-the-openid-connect-and-oauth2-middleware-in-katana-3-x/), however it seems I'm running into a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem with my scenario:

I need to call the Graph API to get the additional user attributes for the Claims, but I don't have the token yet (I don't think) at this point in the process to be able to call the API.

Seems like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: claims are defined by AAD, i don`t think you are allow to add extra claim. can you use query string in your redirect url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many solutions here, but two stand out:

1. In securitytokenvalidated you do have a token, the one sent to your app for sign in purposes. You can use it in an onbehalfof flow to get a token for the graph, and use it right within that notification. You can refer to the sample [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/), it's for web API but the concept is the same
2. You can configure your app to access the graph with its own application identity. You can get that token at any time, then. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/)

Comment: I got option 1 to work inside the SecurityTokenValidated notification as shown in the linked example. The only "gotcha" was that you need to to set `SaveSignInToken = true` in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.TokenValidationParameters` or the sign in token won't be available in the BootstrapContext.

Comment: Yep, that is by design, we don't save it by default to keep the size at the absolute minimum if there's no reason to keep the raw bits around. The sample shows how to do that.